# i stack over and over in djjango

Tags: python, django, django-urls

i watched few videos to learn how to use `Django`. a lot of them coming older version of `Django` and because im a beginner in `Django` so it makes it harder. the problem is that in `urls.py` file they are showing how to make it with "url" way and i have the newer version of Django which is showing me with "path" way. what i did wrong here that it does not showing me:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from adoptions import views


urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path("", views.home, name = "home"),

    path("adoptions/(\d+)/", views.pet_detail, name = "pet_detail"),

]
```

cause what i actually did, i looked on the tutorial and implemented on the path. maybe i did it wrong i dont know. and this is not the first time that i stack on the same place.

Comment: What is `(\d+)` used for?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use id of the cat use it like below

```
path("adoptions/<int:id>", views.pet_detail, name = "pet_detail"),
```

or slug

```
path("adoptions/<slug:slug>", views.pet_detail, name = "pet_detail"),
```

Best way to start `Django` is the official documentation first app. It will fix your mindset easily. Though the versions of `Django` are not so much different than each other.

Comment: i tried, sorry it didnt work.

about django you are right. i tried to find info about that and got confused cause it wasnt something specific there.

Comment: what did not work ? did you try "localhost:8000/adoptions/1"

Comment: thank you so much anyways. this is not the first time that i cant figure out this.

Comment: if you want an answer for you question, please add pet_detail view.